# SQLserver WaitType : EXECUTION_PIPE_EVENT_INTERNAL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, wait-types

One of our production Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP1-CU5) 
 experiencing performance issue so I ran the ShortPeriodWaitStats.sql script from Paul S. Randal, SQLskills.com
and the top WaitType is EXECUTION_PIPE_EVENT_INTERNAL it's 50% of all the WaitTypes !
Someone knows something about it ? any tips to track the core pb ?
[image]

Comment: I don't know about this wait but I believe this is benign wait.

Comment: what are your other top wait types and percents?

Comment: https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/execution_pipe_event_internal/ . Also upgrade to latest SP available to see if you experience the issue. Also, out of curiosity, what issue is `EXECUTION_PIPE_EVENT_INTERNAL` causing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx#Anchor_1), `EXECUTION_PIPE_EVENT_INTERNAL` :

> Occurs during synchronization between producer and consumer parts of batch execution that are submitted through the connection context.

The inference here is this is an internal wait type used to denote actions occurring inside the batch execution engine.  Since this is an internal engine wait, the only way you'll be able to accurately diagnose if this is an issue would be to raise it directly with Microsoft.  Alternately, if you are @BobWard or @PaulWhite, you could dig up a Windows Debugger, recreate the issue in a non-production environment, an stop the code in the middle of that wait type.  For the rest of us mere mortals, this deserves a call to Microsoft if you are truly worried about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you ran ShortPeriodWaitStats with the default 30 minutes period, those waits couldn't possibly be the cause of the performance issues, as SQL Server spent only 1.8 seconds on that top wait.

UPDATE: Oops, I was confusing the seconds output with miliseconds, so the output actually shows the full half hour wait (single-threaded).